# Generate a vector for scale_colour_manual using two input vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2

The ggplot2 manual at http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_manual.html suggests using a structure like:

```
values = c("8" = "red","4" = "blue","6" = "darkgreen", "10" = "orange")
```

to assign specific colours to values.

How does one generate this structure from two arrays:

```
A = c("8","4","6","10"); B = c("red","blue","darkgreen","orange")
```

I got as far as:

```
rbind(A,B)
  [,1]  [,2]   [,3]        [,4]    
A "8"   "4"    "6"         "10"    
B "red" "blue" "darkgreen" "orange"
```

But I am not sure how to turn that into an array of "X" = "Y" assignments.

I realise this is a general R question, not one specific to ggplot2. But I'm tagging it ggplot2 in case it helps someone with the same issue in the future. Any advice welcomed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
values = B
names(values) = A
> all.equal(values,
+       c("8" = "red","4" = "blue","6" = "darkgreen", "10" = "orange"))
[1] TRUE
```

The behavior you are after mimics that of a Python dictionary. There are `key`,`value` pairs, and referring to a specific key returns the value. In this R example the `keys` are the names of the character vector, and the `values` are the values inside the vector. For ggplot2 this explicitly couples a key (e.g. `"8"`) to a color value (`"red"`).

Comment: Thanks Paul (sorry for the delay in replying - I thought I would get a notification from stackoverflow, but my settings must have been wrong)

Comment: I also heard back from the helpful people at the ggplot2 forum, who confirmed what you said (and added an additional solution to the original problem of using scale_colour_manual - linked here in case it is of use to anyone): https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/0k9xjSzx6aw